# Compatibility between norm and order relation on $R^n$

Tags: normed-spaces

Is it true that for any norm $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for any $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n), y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|x_i| \leq |y _i|$ for all $i$, we have $N(x) \leq N(y)$？

Comment: No. Consider $ n = 1$ and $ x < 0$ and $y = -\frac12 x$

Comment: The answer is no in general. However, the $p$-norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy a solidity property: if $|y_i|\leq |x_i|$, $1\leq j\leq n$, then $\|y\|_p\leq\|x\|_p$. This property of $p$-norms extends to other spaces, for example $L_p$ spaces.

Comment: @user2628206 Sorry, I changed $x_i \leq y_i$ into $|x_i| \leq |y_i|$ in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been pointed out in the comment that the answer, in general, is no. I'd like to elaborate on why it's the case.

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $(1-t)x+ty\in A$ for all $x,y\in A$ and $t\in[0,1]$, then $A$ is said to be $\textbf{convex}$. If $-x\in A$ for all $x\in A$, then $A$ is said to be $\textbf{symmetric}$.

Given a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, every open ball about $0$ is a bounded convex symmetric open set. We claim, on the other hand, that if $U$ is a bounded convex symmetric open set containing $0$ (bounded and open relative to the usual Euclidean norm), then there exists a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ under which $U$ is the open ball about $0$ of radius $1$.

Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, put
\begin{align*}
\|x\|=\inf\{t>0\colon t^{-1}x\in U\}.
\end{align*}
This is in fact called the $\textbf{Minkowski functional}$ of $U$. It is not hard to see that
\begin{align*}
U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\|x\|<1\}.
\end{align*}
The inequality is strict because $U$ is open.

Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $U$ is open, $\|x\|$ is well-defined (that is, it isn't the infimum of an empty set). If $x\neq 0$, then by boundedness $t^{-1}x\notin U$ for small enough $t$, so $\|x\|\neq 0$. Also $\|\alpha x\|=\alpha\|x\|$ for all $\alpha\geq 0$ and $\|-x\|=\|x\|$ (because $U$ is symmetric).

Since $0\in U$ and $U$ is convex, if $r^{-1}x\in U$ then $t^{-1}x\in U$ for all $t>r>0$. Given $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $s>\|x\|$, $t>\|y\|$, both $s^{-1}x$ and $t^{-1}y$ are in $U$. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{x+y}{s+t}=\frac{s}{s+t}\cdot\frac{x}{s}+\frac{t}{s+t}\cdot\frac{y}{t}\in U
\end{align}
by convexity, so $\|x+y\|\leq s+t$. Since $s$ and $t$ are arbitrary, $\|x+y\|\leq\|x\|+\|y\|$. This proves $\|\cdot\|$ to be a norm.

Now back to the original problem. To find a counterexample, fix $n=2$, and let $U$ be a thin open rectangle symmetric about $0$ and the line $x_1=x_2$. Then a point $x$ on the tip of the rectangle would have larger coordinates than some point $y$ outside $U$, but $\|x\|<1\leq\|y\|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n = 1$, it's true by using absolute homogeneity of norm.

If $n \geq 2$, it's false and here is a counterexample : for all $x = (x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1})$, $\|x\| := \text{max}_{y\in [0, 1]} |\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_iy^{i}|$. Then $\|\|$ is a norm on $R^n$. Let $x = (1, 2, 0, \ldots, 0), y = (-2, 2, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Then $\|x\| = 3, \|y\| = 2$.